# Como concatenar String dentro de um laço de repetição?

Tags: php, string, loop

Preciso juntar alguns valores em uma *string*.

Como faço para concatenar valores em uma *string* com um laço de repetição.

Exemplo:

```
for($c=0; $c < $tam; $c++){
    //concatenar sempre o valor
    $minhastring = $valor[$c].',';
}
```

Ou seja, eu preciso que cada vez que cada vez que entre no laço a variável `$mihastring` vá concatenando os valores de modo que fique:

```
 $minhastring = $valor[0].','.$valor[1].','.$valor[2].','.$valor[3].',';
```

Comment: Você quer repetir `$valor` uma quantidade de vezes? Ou essa variável está errada aí?

Comment: Sim, na verdade essa variável $valor é dinâmica, pois vem de um array...aí fica $valor[$c]

Comment: cada vez que entra no laço o valor dela fica diferente....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz a primeira forma seguindo o exemplo colocado na pergunta original, repetindo o valor. Já duvidada que fosse isto, mas respondi assim mesmo. Tem maneiras mais simples de fazer isto.

A segunda é o jeito de fazer o que realmente deseja, de acordo com os comentários e edição da pergunta. E a terceira é a forma simplificada para obter o mesmo resultado.

```
//solução baseada na pergunta original
$tam = 4;
$minhastring = '';
$valor = 'teste';
for ($i = 0; $i < $tam; $i++) $minhastring .= $valor . ',';
$minhastring = substr($minhastring, 0, -1);
echo $minhastring . "\n";
//solução para a pergunta real
$minhastring = '';
$valor = Array('teste0', 'teste1', 'teste2', 'teste3');
$tam = count($valor); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $tam; $i++) $minhastring .= $valor[$i] . ',';
$minhastring = substr($minhastring, 0, strlen($minhastring) - 1);
echo $minhastring . "\n";
//a mesma solução com função pronta - recomendada
$minhastring = implode($valor, ",");
echo $minhastring;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/FPHjPI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pxmxzmkq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ConcatLoop.php).

Answer (score 4):

Se a variável for um array, e quiser delimitar os elementos por virgulas pode usar apenas um `implode()`.

```
echo implode(',', $valor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) para isso:

```
$valor = 'palavra,';              // a cadeia de caracteres que será repetida
$string = str_repeat($valor, 3);  // geramos uma nova cadeia com a quantidade de repetições como parâmetro
$string = substr($string, 0, -1); // tiramos a vírgula ao final da cadeia gerada
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitua o *operador* `=` por `.=`

```
for($c=0; $c < $tam; $c++){
    //concatenar sempre o valor
    $minhastring .= $valor[$c] . ',';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode concatenar a cada loop com o operador `.=`

```
$str = '';

for($c=0; $c < $tam; $c++){
    $str .= $valor[$c] . ', ';
}
```

Voce também vai precisar remover a ultima virgula

```
substr(str, 0, -1);
```