# Como pegar todo o resultado de um for, e fazer que se torne uma unica variavel

Tags: php

Digamos que eu tenho um for! E que o resultado do for seja " 1 2 3 4 5 6", só que cada número é uma linha!!

Como pegar todas essas linhas e fazer com que ela se torne uma única variável?

Comment: Pode transformar em um array com `var[] = $i` ou concatenar como uma string usando `$var .= $i`

Comment: Não querendo pedir de mais!! Poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: vc quer um string? ou array?

Comment: O que você achar mais viável.

Comment: É isso? eu não sei o que é viável no seu caso, gerar um array do mesmo array não faz muito sentido, igual está na pergunta.

Comment: Meu caso era mais curiosidade!! Pra ver como se vazia!! Pois não tinha noção!! Com sua resposta tive uma melhor noção e consegui fazer o que eu queria! Obrigado

Comment: Tem outras opções: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88228/91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso através de uma string, concatenando os valores com `.=` ou seja os números ficam todos juntos.

```
<?php

$arr = range(1,6);
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $item){
    $str .= ' '.$item;
}

echo $str;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/F6O4Nu)