# Dividir array com virgula?

Tags: php

Recebo assim os dados

```
Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => python
    [2] => javascript
)
```

como faço para receber assim com vírgula?

Exemplo:

```
php, python, javascript
```

Comment: Ok vou visualizar

Comment: OI anderson nao e isso gostaria de receber os dados com virgula

Comment: Sim, basta ler as respostas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88240/5878

Comment: Na verdade quero que ele de um loop

Comment: Por quê se essa função faz exatamente o que você precisa?

Comment: @HemersonPrestes você não quer com as funções já pronta você quer com uma estrutura de repetição?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu caso acredito que a função `implode` do `PHP` já resolve:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

Exemplo:

```
<?php

   $array = array('php', 'python', 'javascript');
   $separado_por_virgula = implode(", ", $array);

   print $separado_por_virgula; // php, python, javascript
```

Comment: como que ficari aqui    print_r ($_POST['programacao']);

Comment: Estou enviando os dados via post

Comment: Então você recebe com virgulas e quer converter para array? é isso?

Comment: Por favor favoreça as perguntas e ou respostas existentes clicando no Botão "Sinaliza" e indicando uma pergunta como duplicata.